# How to allow action using security component?

Tags: security, cakephp, authentication

I am getting this error

```
Call to undefined method SecurityComponent::allowedActions()
```

When I try to allow singup action in controller like this

```
public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Security->allowedActions(array('sign-up'));
            $this->Auth->allow('login','signup','index','activate','logout','forgot','reset','display');
            if($this->Auth->user('id')) {
                $this->set('logged_in', true);
            } else {
                $this->set('logged_in', false);
            }
        }

        public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

if i remove

```
$this->Security->allowedActions(array('sign-up'));
```

when I submit signup form, It shows your request has ben blackholed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method, `allowedActions` is a *property* of the `SecurityComponent`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::$allowedActions

```
$this->Security->allowedActions = array('sign-up');
```

Also you are using `signup` in `AuthComponent::allow()`, so make sure `sign-up` is really the correct name of the action (which I really doubt as this would be invalid PHP syntax).